# How to use Spring Security .antMatchers() with multiple paths

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Is there a difference if I use Spring Securitys "antMatchers()"-method like

```
.antMatchers(
    "/",
    "/app/**",
    "/profiles/**",
    "/captcha/**",
    c440_START_PAGE,
    FAVICON_ICO,
    C440_LOGIN,
    getCustomerRessourcePath(),
    getCustomerWebRessourcePath(),
    "/services/userService/**",
    "/services/applicationService/**",
    "/services/textContentService/**",
    "/services/textContentBlockService/**",
    "/services/menuItemService/**",
    "/services/calculatorService/**"
).permitAll()
```

or instead

```
.antMatchers("/").permitAll()
.antMatchers("/app/**").permitAll()
.antMatchers("/profiles/**").permitAll()
.antMatchers("/captcha/**").permitAll()
.antMatchers(c440_START_PAGE).permitAll()
.antMatchers(FAVICON_ICO).permitAll()
.antMatchers(C440_LOGIN).permitAll()
.antMatchers(getCustomerRessourcePath()).permitAll()
.antMatchers(getCustomerWebRessourcePath()).permitAll()
.antMatchers("/services/userService/**").permitAll()
.antMatchers("/services/applicationService/**").permitAll()
.antMatchers("/services/textContentService/**").permitAll()
.antMatchers("/services/textContentBlockService/**").permitAll()
.antMatchers("/services/menuItemService/**").permitAll()
.antMatchers("/services/calculatorService/**").permitAll()
```

? I'm new to Spring Security and not sure about this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both of them are same with your implementation. But the second way provides more flexibility in providing role based authorization etc.

For eg, if you want the role `ADMIN` to be authorized to access `"/"` and the role `USER` to be authorized to access `"/app/*"`, then that would be achieved as below:

```
.antMatchers("/").hasRole("ADMIN")
.antMatchers("/app/**").hasRole("USER")
```

Do note that `.permitAll()` needs to be added only once at the end for every set of patterns with same configuration and not necessarily on every line.

One of the signatures of `antMatchers` method is

```
public C antMatchers(java.lang.String... antPatterns)
```

That means you can pass one or more patterns to the method. More on that can be found on the spring [documentation for antMatchers](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/AbstractRequestMatcherRegistry.html#antMatchers-java.lang.String...-)